Wildcard route for ASP.NET Web API
In our ASP.NET Web API project written in C#, we need to route the below endpoints to a single action method with WildCard route in the API:
http://mycomparydomain.com/api/records/recordsearch?recordModule=45314xx
http://mycomparydomain.com/api/records/itemsearch?itemcategory=1245xx
http://mycomparydomain.com/api/records/item/itemid1234
http://mycomparydomain.com/api/records/itembytype?itemtype=common

This is what I am thinking about the controller implementation:
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class RecordsController : Controller
{   
    [HttpGet("{*}")]        
    public async Task<string> Get([FromQuery] string query)
    {
        // API code
    }
}

Is that possible to do so?
If not, what could be possible way to set wildcard route for that?
Check the question in ChatGTP and it is suggesting to use  route as [HttpGet("{*path}")] 
Again, it is not the format I need here.

I am not sure about business use case for using one controller for all requests but even if you use [HttpGet("{*path}")] you have to filter the request inside using if/else, so its always recommended to use multiple methods as it improves readability and maintainability. you can declare [Route("api/records")] on controller level create multiple Action Methods.
